# Differentiate different objects in same Django array

Tags: python, arrays, django, object

I have an problem, I have two different objects in the same array, they have some arguments in common, so I can access them having no problem.

Now I want to know how can I auto-detect what object I'm accessing to in order to make further actions.

```
if len(theArray) > 0:
  sol = []
  for ea in elArray:
    ...
    if ea is Type1:
      ...
    elif ea is Type2:
      ...
    else:
      ...
```

Thanks

Comment: So? Doesn't it work that way?

Comment: I want to know if this works, haven't tryed because I don't know if it's even possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the `is` operator with the `isinstance` function:

```
class Foo: pass
f = Foo()
f is Foo # False
isinstance(f,Foo) # True
```

`is`, in Python, means "these two objects are the same". `isinstance` means "does this object inherit from this class".